# Fancybox gallery without a href?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I want to make fancybox gallery with img without using links (a href)? How i can do that?

HTML:

```
<div id="foo2">
        <img src="/images/banners/001.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
        <img src="/images/banners/002.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
        <img src="/images/banners/003.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
        <img src="/images/banners/004.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
        <img src="/images/banners/005.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
        <img src="/images/banners/006.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
        <img src="/images/banners/007.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
        <img src="/images/banners/008.jpg" rel="downslider" alt="" width="80" height="80" />
.....
</div>
```

JS (now it works with single images, without gallery effect):

```
$("#foo2 img").click(function(e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
        var content = '<img src="' + url + '" rel="'+ rel + '" />';
        $.fancybox({
            'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
            'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
            'speedIn'       :   600, 
            'speedOut'      :   200, 
            'overlayShow'   :   false,
            'content' : content
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot have a gallery using the manual method `.click()` unless you set all the elements of the gallery inside the fancybox script itself like:

```
$("#foo2 img").click(function(e) {
 $.fancybox([
  'images/01.jpg',
  'images/02.jpg', // etc
  ],{
   // fancybox options 
   'type': 'image' // etc.
 }); // fancybox
}); // click
```

However, to make it work the way you want and simulate a regular fancybox gallery without using links (`<a>` tags with a `href` attributes ), you would need to create your own function with your own custom navigation methods.

Without changing your `HTML`, try this `JS`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function fancyBoxMe(index){
 var gallerySize = $("#foo2 img").size();
 if((index+1) == gallerySize){ nexT = 0 } else { nexT = index+1}
 if(index == 0){ preV = (gallerySize-1) } else { preV = index-1}
 var tarGet = $('#foo2 img').eq(index).attr('src');
 $.fancybox({
  'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
  'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
  'speedIn' : 600, 
  'speedOut' : 200, 
  'overlayShow' : false,
  'href': tarGet,
  'titlePosition': 'inside',
  'titleFormat' : function(){
    return 'Image '+(index+1)+' of '+gallerySize+'<a id="preV" href="javascript:;" onclick="fancyBoxMe('+preV+')">prev</a> <a id="nexT" href="javascript:;" onclick="fancyBoxMe('+nexT+')">next</a>';
  }
 }); // fancybox
} // fancyBoxMe
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#foo2 img").each(function(i){
  $(this).bind('click', function(){
   fancyBoxMe(i);
  }); //bind        
 }); //each
}); // ready
</script>
```

That creates a fancybox gallery from the `<img>` tags, with a nice cycling effect. Also, with a little of `CSS` we can have the navigation controls using the fancybox arrow icons. [See a working example here](http://picssel.com/playground/jquery/galleryIMGtag_11feb12.html).

Since the navigation control is totally manual, you don't actually need the `rel` attribute on the `<img>` tag.

**Please notice** that the code above is for Fancybox v1.3.x (I assumed you are using v1.3.x because the API options).

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
$(".CLASSNAME").each(function(){

   $(this).fancybox({

       href : $(this).attr('src')

   });


});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".fancy").each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<a class="fancybox" href="'+$(this).attr('src')+'">'+$(this)[0].outerHTML +'</a>');
    }).promise().done(function(){ $('.fancybox').fancybox(); });

});
```

then:

```
<img class="fancy" src="1.jpg" alt="" />
<img class="fancy" src="2.jpg" alt="" />
```

and then with further customization

```
<img class="fancy" src="2.jpg" data-small-image="small2.jpg" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 2):

the easy way, you can add anchor/a tag in each img from id='foo2'.

```
$('#foo2 img').each(function (){
 var currentImage = $(this); 
 currentImage.wrap("<a class='fancybox' href='" + currentImage.attr("src") + "'</a>"); });
```

And then:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    openEffect  : 'none',
    closeEffect : 'none',
    beforeShow : function() {
    this.title =  'Image ' + (this.index + 1) + ' of ' + this.group.length + ' '+(this.title ? '' + this.title + '' : '');
   },
   helpers  : {
        thumbs  : {
            width   : 50,
            height  : 50
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the fancybox call on the images:

```
$('#foo2 img').fancybox({
  'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
  'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
  'speedIn'       :   600, 
  'speedOut'      :   200, 
  'overlayShow'   :   false
});
```

should work but i haven't tested it...

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the clicked image inside a href and than trigger the fancybox to show the image.

```
 $(document).on('click tap', 'img.fancybox', function(e)
 {
     // Already wrapped a fancybox href around the clicked image
     if ($(this).parent().is('a')) {
         return false;
     }

    $(this)
    .wrap('<a href="' + this.src + '" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="' + this.alt + '" />')
    .parent()
    .fancybox({})
    .trigger('click');
});
```