# How to set group for images without link in Fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

Currently I use this code for apply Fancybox to a set of images not wrapped by tag `<A>`:

```
$("img[alt=lightbox]").each(function(){
   $(this).fancybox({ href : $(this).attr('src') });
});
```

Now I'd like to add to the same group all images added in this way.

I tried with:

```
$("img[alt=lightbox]").each(function(){
   $(this).attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery");
   $(this).fancybox({ href : $(this).attr('src') });
});
```

Without luck, do you have any advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox gallery without a href?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240436/fancybox-gallery-without-a-href)

Comment: the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244921/1055987 includes a demo

Comment: Thanks but this seems doesn't work with Fancybox 2.

Comment: well, it does work ... see my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer for this question **[Fancybox gallery without a href?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240436/fancybox-gallery-without-a-href)** was written for fancybox v1.3.4.

The same solution would work equally for fancybox v2.x, however bear in mind that *fancybox v2.x API options are new and not compatible with previous versions* ... so you have actually to upgrade the API options to make it work with v2.x

Here is the v2.x update :

The basic html :

```
 <div id="myContainer">
  <img src="images/01t.jpg" data-href="images/01.jpg" alt=""  />
  <img src="images/02t.jpg" data-href="images/02.jpg" alt=""  />
  <img src="images/03t.jpg" data-href="images/03.jpg" alt=""  />
  <img src="images/04t.jpg" data-href="images/04.jpg" alt=""  />
  <img src="images/05t.jpg" data-href="images/05.jpg" alt=""  />
 </div>
```

... **notice** that we used the (HTML5) `data-*` (`data-href`) attribute to target the big images and let the `src` attribute to target the thumbnails.

Then the js :

```
// the function we call when we click on each img tag
function fancyBoxMe(e) {
    var numElemets = $("#myContainer img").size();
    if ((e + 1) == numElemets) {
        nexT = 0
    } else {
        nexT = e + 1
    }
    if (e == 0) {
        preV = (numElemets - 1)
    } else {
        preV = e - 1
    }
    var tarGet = $('#myContainer img').eq(e).data('href');
    $.fancybox({
        href: tarGet,
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: 'inside'
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            this.title = 'Image ' + (e + 1) + ' of ' + numElemets + ' :: <a href="javascript:;" onclick="fancyBoxMe(' + preV + ')">prev</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="javascript:;" onclick="fancyBoxMe(' + nexT + ')">next</a>'
        }
    }); // fancybox
} // fancyBoxMe

// bind click to each img tag 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myContainer img").each(function (i) {
        $(this).bind('click', function () {
            fancyBoxMe(i);
        }); //bind      
    }); //each
}); // ready
```

And of course, here is **[the DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/galleryIMGtag_11feb13.html)**

Comment: Thank you, but this add a different navigation method using different arrows. Isn't possible do the same thing but with arrows of fancybox?

Comment: @FezVrasta if you are a developer, I guess you won't find difficult to customize it with a bit of css

Comment: I'd like to not hack Fancybox, so I was asking you if there is a method for set manualy the "next" and "prev" links. I seen in docs that there is an option for change it (tpl) and an option for force arrows to be visible, but arrows simply doesn't become visible.

Comment: you wouldn't be hacking fancybox, you would be adding your own css. Check the example for v1.3.4 http://stackoverflow.com/a/9244921/1055987 ... it uses the fancybox icons with a custom css

Comment: anyway, we are already hacking fancybox since it is meant to be used with anchors and not with `img` tags ... this is not an standard but a customized solution

Answer (score 1):

According to fancy box:

> Note - Galleries are created from elements who have the same "rel" tag, example:

Look at bottom of page [here](http://fancybox.net/howto)

So try setting the rel:

```
$("img[alt=lightbox]").each(function(){
  $(this).attr("rel", "gallery");
  $(this).fancybox({ href : $(this).attr('src') });
});
```

Comment: For Fancybox data-fancybox-group and rel are the same thing. I tried your advice without luck.

Comment: Sorry, thought it might help.