# How to apply lazy load for fancybox images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, lazy-loading

I am running a gallery using fancybox on page load. I am trying to apply lazyload using [jquery lazyload](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) for the images in the fancybox.

But somehow its not working. I changed the jquery.fancybox.js from.

```
image    : '<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />',
```

to

```
image    : '<img class="fancybox-image lazy" data-src="{href}" src="" alt="" />',
```

So the resulted html will be like the following.

```
<img class="fancy-image lazy" data-src="file.jpg" src alt/>
```

I am applying the lazy load like below.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img").lazy();
});
</script>
```

and also i tried delay.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("img").lazy({
    delay: 5000
   });
});
</script>
```

I have also searched through google but i cant able to find anything related to this. Please help me.

Comment: Did you get any error with fire bug on page load ? please explain what is your question .

Comment: Hello @Farshad , i didnt get any error. I am trying to apply lazyload for the images showing in the fancybox. I am loading the fancybox while opening the page itself using triggering the fancybox. I have lot of images in the queue. So while loading the page it will load entire images. so it take too much of time to load all images. Actually whenever i load the page, only the first image in the gallery should load. And in thumbnail of fancybox need to show all images in the gallery. I am trying this with lazyload and is there any alternative for this process. Thank you.

Comment: I think this link useful for you [link](http://www.resrc.it/demos/modal)

Comment: Hello @Farshad , I check the link. There the fancybox is loading after the image click. i am not loading the fancybox after page load. I am loading the fancybox straightaway when i open a page. i need to reduce the time taken to load the page by loading only the first image  and all the thumbnails, whenever i load that particular page in fancybox.

Comment: put your try (code) in jsfiddle if you want . I'l check it.

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcjaj2xw/)

Comment: take a look at this [demo](http://www.hishamomran.com/zahabia3/gallery.html)

Answer (score 1):

Respecting to your comments my Solution is :

[Source Code](http://jsfiddle.net/hrgry79b/5/)

[Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/hrgry79b/5/show/)

```
 $(function() {
          $("img").lazyload();
      });


    $('.nav_wrap_start').delay(300).animate({top:'0px'},1500).queue(function(next) { $(this).attr('class','nav_wrap'); next(); });
    $('.welcome_wrap').delay(2100).fadeIn(500);
    $('.nav_wrapleft').delay(300).fadeIn(700);

    // fancybox settings
    $("a.fancyboxnumber").fancybox({
        'titlePosition'     : 'outside',
        'overlayColor'      : '#000',
        'overlayOpacity'    : 0.9
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

### 1. Summary

Use this construction:

```html
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="{{Link to your image}}"><img class="KiraNotLazy" data-src="{{Link to your image}}" alt="{{Your image description}}"></a>
```

- `{{Link to your image}}` — it must be same for `href` and `alt` attributes, if you use same image for thumbnail

---

### 2. Demonstration

- [**Repl.it sources**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraJQueryLazyFancyBox-Demo):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JQuery Lazy + FancyBox</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fancyapps/fancybox@3.5.6/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-lazy@1.7.10/jquery.lazy.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="KiraScript.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/fancyapps/fancybox/dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="KiraStyle.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/15Nghv2.jpg"><img class="KiraNotLazy" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/15Nghv2.jpg" alt="Kira in winter 1"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/5Iotirp.jpg"><img class="KiraNotLazy" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/5Iotirp.jpg" alt="Kira in winter 2"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/d6mDu6F.jpg"><img class="KiraNotLazy" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/d6mDu6F.jpg" alt="Kira in winter 3"></a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://i.imgur.com/fh3wGvs.jpg"><img class="KiraNotLazy" data-src="https://i.imgur.com/fh3wGvs.jpg" alt="Kira in winter 4"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
body {
  background-color: aliceblue
}
img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 100rem;
  max-width: 100%
}
```

```js
// [INFO] JQuery Lazy basic usage:
// http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/
$(function() {
    $('.KiraNotLazy').Lazy();
});

// [INFO] FancyBox3 options:
// https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/#options
$('[data-fancybox="gallery"]').fancybox({
    buttons: [
        "zoom",
        "share",
        "slideShow",
        "fullScreen",
        "download",
        "thumbs",
        "close"
    ],
});
```

- [**Repl.it demo**](https://kirajquerylazyfancybox-demo--kristinita.repl.co/):

[image: KiraJQueryLazyFancyBox--ezgif_minified]

---

### 3. Disclaimer

This is solution for:

- JQuery 3.3.1
- JQuery Lazy 1.7.10
- FancyBox 3.5.6

In the future versions my answer may not work.

---

### 4. Syntactic sugar

If you have same images as thumbnails, you can use [**this script**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25908042/5951529), modified for FancyBox 3. You can remove `a` wrapper around `img`.

- [**Repl.it sources**](https://repl.it/@Kristinita/KiraJQueryLazyFancyBox-awrapperdisable)
- [**Repl.it demo**](https://kirajquerylazyfancybox-awrapperdisable--kristinita.repl.co/)

Comment: Please, comment your downvote. Let me know what's wrong with this answer so we can make this site better. Thanks.