# Image not showing in IE form base64

Tags: c#, jquery, html, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have stored the image in Oracle DB in CLOB when i am converting it back using base64 in image source it works fine in Chrome & Firefox but in Internet Explorer. some part of the image is shown after that dots appeared in remaining Picture.

I try to solve this problem through simple as well as through programmatically but same result.

Here is my **html**

```
     <a class="fancybox" href="@images.IMG" 
data-fancybox-group="gallery"> <span style="color:#428bca;font-size:34px;margin-top:-34px;
float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></span></a>
```

Here `@images.IMG` contains simple clob data without any conversion
i am using Fancybox a `JQuery` plugin to show pictures.

**C#** way

```
byte[] byt = Convert.FromBase64String(imgclobdata);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byt);
   var img= "data:image/jpg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray(), 0, ms.ToArray().Length);
```

[image: Attached Sample]

Answer (score 1):

There's a limit of how much data you can cram into `data` uri. Internet Explorer's limit is lower than Firefox's or Chrome's (and varies between versions).

In short: don't do that. Data scheme is acceptable only for small files.

Comment: but if i show the image on page instead of any jquery plugin then why it is displaying correctly

Comment: @MohsinMustufa Show the code for both versions (edit the question). http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @MohsinMustufa You're trying to discuss code which you haven't shown. It isn't productive. You haven't read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, have you?

Answer (score 1):

[Internet Explorer has a limit on maximum URL length of 2083 characters.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427/en-us)

If you want to circumvent this limitation you can place your base64 image inside of the `img` tag's `src` attribute:

```
<img src="Base64StuffGoesHere" />
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240436/fancybox-gallery-without-a-href) has some nice answers on how to make fancybox work without using `href` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Special Thanks to @Yuriy

This work for me in all browers

```
 <span style="color:#428bca;font-size:34px;margin-top:-34px;
float:right;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" onclick="showImg('@images.IMG');"></span>

    function showImg(data){
 $.fancybox([
  'images/01.jpg',
  'images/02.jpg', // etc
  ],{
   // fancybox options 
   'type': 'image' // etc.
 }); // fancybox
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending Clob string, create a ashx handler and write down your content in ashx.

For details you may refer

[Display Image using ashx Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733875/display-image-using-ashx-handler)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me : add a ID attribute to your picture and add the link to this ID

```
promos.Text += "<div class='recent-work-item'>";
promos.Text += "    <em>";
promos.Text += "        <img src='" + image + "' alt='" + title + "' class='img-responsive'>";
promos.Text += "        <a href='http://www.acipa.fr/Blog/post/" + url + "' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-link'></i></a>";
// this line doesn't work on IE because URL of href is too long
//promos.Text += "        <a href='" + image + "' class='fancybox-button' title='' data-rel='fancybox-button'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>";

// this line works on IE because it is an internal link:
promos.Text += "        <a href='#" + postid + "' class='fancybox-button' title='' data-rel='fancybox-button'><i class='fa fa-search'></i></a>";
promos.Text += "    </em>";
promos.Text += "</div>";
// add this img with an ID for the link
promos.Text += "        <img src='" + image + "' alt='" + title + "' class='img-responsive' id='" + postid + "'>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because of this uri limitation you shouldn't use anchor tag, instead you can try this:

```
<div class="fancybox" data-fancybox data-src="data:image/png;base64, ..." data-type="image">
 <img src="data:image/png;base64, ..." alt="image">
</div>
```